# How to expand $\pi$ in non-decimal bases?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, number-systems

I was reading about $\pi$ converted into other base systems. We all know $\pi$ in base $10$:

$$\pi_{10} = 3.1415926535897932384626433(...)$$

but how has this been converted into, say, base $11$, where it reads:

$$\pi_{11} = 3.16150702865A48233(...)$$

I cannot get the process.

I know what base $11$ is but I thought the conversion were like $digit by digit". Yet just from the beginning something changes:

$3.14$ becomes $3.16$, but both $4$ in base eleven is still $4$.

How then has this conversion been made?

Comment: Repeated subtraction of fractions. It's clearly between $3+1/11$ and $3+2/11$, so the first digit after the undecimal (hendecimal?) point is $1$. Similarly, it's between $3+1/11+6/11^2$ and $3+1/11+7/11^2$, so the next digit is $6$ etc.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, wow. That is undoubtely cool!

Comment: $[\pi]=3$, so first "digit" is $3$. Now subtract $3$ and multiply by $11$; the part to the left of the point is $1$, which is the next digit. Subtract $1$ and multiply by $11$; the part to the left of the point is $6$, so $6$ is the next digit. Continue; Subtract the most recent digit, multiply by $11$, what's to the left of the point is the next digit.